# Typescript error: Property 'htmlType' is missing in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

After upgrade to typescript 3.0.1 and antd 3.8.0 I have next compilation error:
Property 'htmlType' is missing in type '{ children: Element; id: string; className: string; shape: "circle"; }'.

```
<Button id="goToTopButton" className="scroll-to-top-button" shape="circle">
                        <i className="material-icons">arrow_upward<i/>
</Button>
```

And similar errors for another components like Modal and so on. 
Does any one may help to fix it?

Comment: I'm having this error too... Any update on this?

Comment: look at next issue https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/11677